# How to force timeout for DriverManager.getConnection() method call?

Tags: java, timeout, database-connection

I have an application which will establish DB connection with MySQL and execute queries. Sometimes the `DriverManager.getConnection()` method call takes 2 seconds and sometimes it takes 30 seconds. Is there any way to control this method to timeout after 2 seconds?

`DriverManager.setLoginTimeout()` doesn't seem to work.

Actually, am able to set timeout for `statement.executeQuery()` by sleeping the thread for my timeout value and closing the connection after wakeup. But its the connection establishment part where I couldn't really set the timeout.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: which driver are you using and for which data base?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's no other options, you could always just execute the call in a separate thread, which you abort/ignore if it doesn't finish in 2 secs.

**EDIT**
Here's an example of what I was thinking:

```
public class Dummy extends Thread {
private volatile Connection conn = null;
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("foobar") ;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
static public Connection getConnection() {
    Dummy d = new Dummy() ;
    d.start() ;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000) ;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    return d.conn ;
}
}
```

Then you can just call the static Dummy.getConnection() method other places in your code. One drawback is that this method will always take 2 secs, but changing it to return immediately when the thread is finished isn't too hard.

Comment: How to abort the thread? Interrupting the thread after 2 secs doesn't work.

Comment: Well, if you think you have to abort the Thread, you could always just call stop() on it, but that's a deprecated method so read up on any potential pitfalls in the docs first. You could also just let it continue to run as you ignore it and move on.

Comment: Sorry, but the thread.stop() says "If the target thread waits for long periods (on a condition variable, for example), the interrupt method should be used to interrupt the wait." But in my case interrupt() doesn't help. May i know the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the socketTimeout (Time in milliseconds) on the connection URL or on the connection pool (if you are using pooling). Take care not to set this value too low or it will overwrite the statement timeout value.

```
try {
    this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("url?socketTimeout=2000") ;
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or

```
<jdbc-connection-pool 
                     connection-validation-method="table"
                     fail-all-connections="true"
                     idle-timeout-in-seconds="300"
                     is-connection-validation-required="true"
                     statement-timeout-in-seconds="2"
                     validation-table-name="dual"
                     ..... >
   <property name="databaseName" value="...."/>
   <property name="serverName" value="....."/>
   <property name="User" value="....."/>
   <property name="Password" value="......."/>
   <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://...../...."/>
   <property name="driverClass" value="...."/>
   <property name="socketTimeout" value="2000"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

Setting this fixed the timeout issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you to codebolt, I don't know if it's the best solution but this works for me. A 10 seconds time out.

```
public class Dummy extends Thread {
             private volatile java.sql.Connection conn = null;
             private boolean sleep = true;
            @Override
             public void run() {
                 try {

                     String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
                     Class.forName(driver).newInstance();                       
                     //timeout
                     DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10);
                     this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
                     sleep = false;
                 } catch (Exception e) {}
             }
             public java.sql.Connection getConnection() {
                 Dummy d = new Dummy() ;
                 d.start() ;
                 try {
                     for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
                         //Wait 1 second
                         if (d.sleep){
                             Thread.sleep(1000);  
                         }
                     }  
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                 return d.conn ;
             }
             }
```

And the call:

```
Dummy a = new Dummy();
connection = a.getConnection();
if (connection != null) {....
```

Comment: Posted by an [anonymous user](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2889625): `If you make the getConnection() method static, you don't have to create object a which is never used.  Going further, you could make the driver class name, URL, user name, and passwords arguments to getConnection() and have something quite general purpose.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ExecutorService` interface from Java. Below is a sample of what you need to do.

```
Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(YOUR_METHOD);
future.get(TIMEOUT_YOU_NEED, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I expanded upon the answers by CodeBolt and anpadia to make the following complete class. It has only one static method that accepts all needed connection parameters, including the timeout duration. Additionally, the method wil also throw SQLException and ClassNotFoundException if they occur.

Usage:

```
String connectionUrl = "...";
String user = "...";
String password = "...";
String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"; // for example

int timeoutInSeconds = 5;

Connection myConnection =
    ConnectWithTimeout.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, password, driver, timeoutInSeconds);
```

Below is the implementation:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class ConnectWithTimeout extends Thread {

    private static String _url;
    private static String _user;
    private static String _password;
    private static String _driver;

    private static volatile Connection _connection = null;
    private static volatile boolean _sleep = true;
    private static volatile SQLException _sqlException = null;
    private static volatile ClassNotFoundException _classNotFoundException = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Class.forName(_driver);
            _connection = DriverManager.getConnection(_url, _user, _password);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            _sqlException = ex;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            _classNotFoundException = ex;
        }
        _sleep = false;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(String url, 
                                           String user, 
                                           String password, 
                                           String driver, 
                                           int timeoutInSeconds) 
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        checkStringOrThrow(url,      "url");
        checkStringOrThrow(user,     "user");
        checkStringOrThrow(password, "password");
        checkStringOrThrow(driver,   "driver");

        if (timeoutInSeconds < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "timeoutInSeconds must be positive");
        }

        _url = url;
        _user = user;
        _password = password;
        _driver = driver;

        ConnectWithTimeout conn = new ConnectWithTimeout();
        conn.start();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < timeoutInSeconds; i++) {
                if (_sleep) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }

        if (_sqlException != null) {
            throw _sqlException;
        }

        if (_classNotFoundException != null) {
            throw _classNotFoundException;
        }

        return _connection;
    }

    private static void checkStringOrThrow(String variable, String variableName) {
        if (variable == null || variable.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "String is null or empty: " + variableName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example how to use:

http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/sql/DriverManager/setLoginTimeout%28int%20seconds%29.html

Comment: But I think setLoginTimeout() implementation is not avaliable for the jdbc-mysql driver.

Comment: ok se these:  http://www.freak-search.com/en/thread/796051/jdbc_mysql_encoding_utf-8_to_latin1

Comment: @Haroldis: That link has rotted away. Please include your findings in the answer.