# How to manage MySQL Connections properly?

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I am working on a server-application written in java.
There are up to 30 client requests per second, for every request a specific mysql table entry gets updated.

All the server threads use a single mySQL Connection, they obtain it from a singleton class. Then the server thread creates a Statement and executes a update query.

Although I close all the created Statements after execution, the server stops updating the mySQL table after some hours.

What could be wrong? Is this setup a misconcept?

Comment: You may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683949/connection-timeout-for-drivermanager-getconnection. You may also implement or [reuse](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pooll) to manage your `Connection`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, your connection was closed due to timeout.
You can make use of [Connection#isValid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)) in order to verify whether or not your connection is still open.

You may take a look at [Connection timeout for DriverManager getConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683949/connection-timeout-for-drivermanager-getconnection). There are several good tips listed.

Also, You may consider the use of [Connection Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) in your code. [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, a connection pool seems the way to go.
I am now looking for an easy example, as I don't understand the usage of connection pools yet...

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/jdbcconnectionpooling.html
I think I will try it this way. Would it be right to make this Thread a singleton, start it in my main class and let all the threads obtain their connections from it?
And another question: How big should the connection pool be for ~30 requests/second?

Unfortunately I can not test it yet, have to wait for the evening :)

Comment: You're welcome. Its not required to implement Connection Pool from scratch. There are several jars to choose from: [C3PO](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html), [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp)

Comment: You will be able to fine tune your connection pool later, I guess. As for now, set any reasonable min poll size and max pool size and let connection pool figure out how to adjust pool size.