# How to set jdbc connection lifetime and timeout?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to set jdbc connection lifetime and lifespan how do i do it.

I tried using properties.

```
Properties info = new properties();
info.put(user,"username");
info.put(password,"password");
info.put(connection lifetime, 0);


DriverManager.getConnection(server,info)
```

But this didn't work please help.

Comment: maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683949/connection-timeout-for-drivermanager-getconnection

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The lifetime is not getting set it connection lifetime is still about 15minutes

Comment: @rbntd it only sets timeout how to set lifetime

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
info.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, "2000");
```

Reference: [Setting Network Timeout for JDBC connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822552/setting-network-timeout-for-jdbc-connection)

Note that not all JDBC JARs support setting a timeout this way.  Sometimes you have to do it programatically.

Comment: @RahulSingh Can you configure this from Oracle?  This doesn't seem like a Java problem.

Comment: I want to keep it open forever the same connection i donot want to use connection pooling

Comment: That sounds like a really bad idea.  If Java drops the connection, scrap it and return it to the pool.

Comment: But is that possible?

Comment: I'm not certain, read here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/optimize.htm#CFHHCICE

Comment: This is for the connection pool stream where as i want for a single connection object