# JDBC DriverManager detect if the user is on the network before trying to connect to the database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I'm working on a Java app that can be used connected to my office network or not.

My problem is that, when the user is not connected, the `DriverManager.getConnection()` takes up to 20 seconds before finally releasing that it can't connect to the database.

Code that connect me or not to the server :

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    try{
        //cnx is my Connection object
        if(cnx ==null || cnx.isClosed()){
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //Get the connection if possible
            cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, password);
        }
        /*
        Basically, I'm just checking if "ConfigUser.isConnected()" is true
        later in the code to know if I should try to execute SQL queries
        */
        ConfigUser.setConnected(true);
        return cnx;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    ConfigUser.setConnected(false);
    return null;
}
```

I've tried to use the `DriverManager.setLoginTimeout()` function but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683949/connection-timeout-for-drivermanager-getconnection

Comment: They are talking about the life of the connection, which is not my question

Comment: How are you connecting to your office network? Is it part of your application or is it a separate VPN application that the user has to start separately?

Comment: @NattyRoots You didn't follow complete post. Same solution as accepted by you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683949/connection-timeout-for-drivermanager-getconnection/10764256#10764256

Comment: @SukhpalSingh Indeed ! My bad, I assumed they were talking about something else after reading the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to `connectionString` [connect timeout in milliseconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html):

```
&connectTimeout=5000
```

> connectTimeout
>
> Timeout for socket connect (in milliseconds), with 0 being no timeout. Only works on JDK-1.4 or newer. Defaults to '0'.

Comment: Well, I'll have to question my life's choices for not seeing that... Thanks man, works like a charm